# How to initialize a NSMutableDictionary of a NSArray of NSStrings from a .plist file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

For example, the dictionary of array of strings, for `who likes what`:

```
@"John"  -> [@"Books", @"TV", @"Poker", nil] 
@"Peter" -> [@"Programming", @"Simsons", nil] 
@"Tim"   -> [@"Travel", @"Photography", nil]
```

How can I initialize the `NSMutableDictionary` for above, say, the data is from a `.plist`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you simply invoke `-writeToFile:` on the `NSDictionary` holding the `NSArray` instances, it will write it out to a plist file that you specify.

Then, you can use `-initWithContentsOfFile:` to re-create that same `NSDictionary`, holding the same `NSArray` data as well.

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty plist file in your project.

Set the root initial value to dictionary.

Add each person as a key and set the value type to array. (right click)

Press the expand button (little plus on right of selected line) to get Item0, Item1, etc for each person. Set the value for each of these. (Books, TV, Poker, etc)

Save the file.

Use

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"<plist name w/out extension" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```